# I don't know how to say that as a native?

Tags: greetings

My professor, who I had work with him before, put a photo with beautiful smile on Whats-App status, I want to say to him that always be happy and I wish that you **always be glad and smiley** or something like that. 
**Be happy and smiley** is correct?

Comment: In personal messages I wouldn't worry too much about "perfect" English.  Sometimes expressing how you really feel, even with grammatical mistakes, is more authentic and pleasant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can say ***Be happy and smiley*** in everyday English, but it is a tiny bit awkward because it seems almost like a command that your friend should follow immediately. It's also a little humorous because of that famous Bobby McFerrin song, "Don't Worry, Be Happy."

It might sound better if you said, ***May you always be happy and smiley***. Or: **I hope you're always this happy and smiley.** That way, it is clear that this is a wish that you have for your friend.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase:

> Be happy

is not ungrammatical, but it's not usually the way a native speaker would express a wish for ongoing happiness. Instead, we'd likely switch the verb to something more enduring.

If I wanted to say what it sounds like you're trying to say, I'd probably word it something like this:

> **Stay** happy and **keep** smiling.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, It was both interesting and useful

Comment: @Stefano - You're welcome. More interesting and useful reading can be found [here](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4744). Keep smiling!